# clojurescript error on including google dependency

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have cljs page where I require a google closure dependency -

```
(ns pm.client.models
  (:require  [google.pubsub.PubSub :as pubsub]))
```

This is the error I see on the loading the html page. The error is logged in the browser's js console -

```
goog.require could not find: goog.storage.mechanism.HTML5LocalStorage
goog.requireclient.js:96
(anonymous function)client.js:20191
client.js:98Uncaught Error: goog.require could not find: goog.storage.mechanism.HTML5LocalStorage
goog.requireclient.js:98
(anonymous function)
```

I dont see any error on compiling the clojurescript using cljs-build.

Comment: Is the cljs-build configured with :optimizations :advanced?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a Google Closure jar with the HTML5LocalStorage lib inside.

It might be either caused by some issues with paths to a third-party jar (unlikely since it's your project that requires it) or because the path (or the name) has changed in the release. Make sure you're not referencing paths from dev release but actually using final release.
Unpack the jar and grep around to see if/where HTML5LocalStorage is.